# AS3 convert a positive number to 1 and a negative number to -1

Tags: actionscript-3, math

There is a simple trick to convert a number to 1 or -1.
Just raise it to the power of 0.
So:

```
 4^0 =  1
-4^0 = -1
```

However, in AS3:

```
Math.pow( 4, 0); // = 1
Math.pow(-4, 0); // = 1
```

Is there a way to get the right answer without an if else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if *without an if/else* includes the ternary operator in your eyes, but if not:

```
// Where x is your input.
var r:int = x < 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

Will be more efficient than `Math.pow()` anyway.

Comment: I should have said without using logic.
But if it's less expensive to do it that way, I'll do it that way.
Thanks!

Comment: @leetheguy Fair enough, I could attempt to find a solution using an inbuilt `Math.*` function if you *want*, but I don't see the benefit.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done bitwise.

Given the number *n* (avg time: 0.0065ms):

```
1 + 2 * (n >> 31);
```

Or slightly slower (avg time: 0.0095ms):

```
(n < 0 && -1) || 1;
```

However, Marty's solution is the fastest (avg time: 0.0055ms)

```
n < 0 ? -1 : 1;
```